# The probability of two measurements being identical when both have measurement errors

Tags: probability, measurement-error, similarities

**Statement:**

Let's assume $ X_i =\{x_1,\ x_2,\ldots,\ x_i \}$
is a set of products that I am interested in their length.
I have two measurement devices that measure the length of these products in random order. In other words, $L^1_{d1}$ and $L^1_{d2}$ are not necessarily the length of $X_1$.
Moreover, I have the measurement error probability function of two measurement devices. For the time being, let's assume this probability function is identical for both devices.

**My questions:**

1- How could I find the match probability between each pair of $L^i_{d1}$ and $L^j_{d2}$ based on the similarity of their length?
I am aware of the matching problem based on the similarity distance matrix, but I am looking for matching probability. In other words, I don't want a one-to-one match; rather, I am interested in a probability matrix of matches.

2- Whereas it is struggling, if it is necessary, I might be able to estimate separate measurement error probability functions for each device. But is there any added value here?

3- What probability theory is behind this problem if any?

Comment: "I have the measurement error probability function of two measurement devices..." and then "I might be able to estimate separate measurement error probability functions for each device" seem to contradict each other...